# Building Ubuntu Linux kernel - what are the various images?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

I just built the Ubuntu linux kernel according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel (which seems to be reasonably up to date according to the September 2019 date).

The target I built is:

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-amd64
```

I have these images (which annoyingly it spits out in the parent directory):

```
linux-buildinfo-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33_amd64.deb
linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33_amd64.deb
linux-headers-5.4.0-29_5.4.0-29.33_all.deb
linux-headers-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33_amd64.deb
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33_amd64.deb
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33_amd64.deb
linux-tools-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33_amd64.deb
```

Whereas in that document it says I should expect something like that:

```
linux-headers-4.8.0-17_4.8.0-17.19_all.deb
linux-headers-4.8.0-17-generic_4.8.0-17.19_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.8.0-17-generic_4.8.0-17.19_amd64.deb
```

Although it does say there may be a `linux-extra-` packge in newer kernels, there's still several discrepancies:

1. My `linux-image-` is unsigned
2. There's no `linux-extra` package, only a `linux-modules-extra`.
3. It doesn't mention to install either of the `linux-modules-` packages, and yet if I don't some of my decivce stop working (Bluetooth/Wifi).

Is there any definitive explanation of all these packages, and which ones exactly I need to replicate the out-of-the-box setup for Ubuntu Focal please?

Comment: You might find useful this answer to this question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197487/what-are-the-deb-files-for-installing-a-kernel-for